# Connecting 3.5" HDD to a Laptop via HDD caddy

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I have an HDD caddy already connected to my laptop with a 2.5" HDD. I want to recover some data from my old 3.5" HDD which has SATA port and 4 pin power port. Can I use a SATA data cable to connect my HDD to the caddy and power it to an external ATX power supply? Or just buy an 3.5" HDD enclosure?

Comment: I'm assuming for now that your HDD caddy does not support the 3.5" HDD size? But yeah extending the SATA data port with SATA cable will work, and also the external ATX power supply. In the end you may just need to consider which one is more efficient (cable tangling mess vs a HDD enclosure/caddy), or which one is more price efficient (sata cable + ext power vs HDD caddy/enclosure). All 3.5" HDD caddy you can use for both 3.5" and 2.5" (the 2.5" HDD will click and sit rather flimsily but works)

Comment: @Darius I have SATA cables ATX PSU from my old unit which works fine. I can't use the mobo since it's the problem why I have to use my laptop for this. Since I'm doing this for one time only, and upon your confirmation that It'll work, I will excluded the idea to buy an enclosure. And yes, I swapped my rom drive to a 2.5'' caddy for more storage option. Thank you